# Installation failure

Tags: boot, livedvd, installation

I have just downloaded Ubuntu and burned an installation DVD. I used it to install Ubuntu on a PC running Windows XP choosing the option to run Ubuntu alongside Windows. I chose to install the additional updates after initial installation.

When I choose Ubuntu from the menu displayed on boot-up I get a purple and yellow screen which is completely blank except for the functioning mouse pointer.

I would be grateful for suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot? Can you open up a terminal by pressing `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1`? Maybe try updating; `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and maybe reinstalling Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall`

What Ubuntu version are you using? I read about problems with 12.10 and some graphics cards (what graphics card do you have?). You might have to switch your currently used/installed driver.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following the [Installation Troubleshooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/installation-guide/i386/boot-troubleshooting.html). The timestamp is a bit dated (for Ubuntu 8.04), but most of the content is still relevant, so you may be able to resolve your problem anyway. At the very least, getting your Installation Report (last step) would be helpful information to accompany your question.